# ASP .Net : Filter ListView items dynamically based on user input

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datapager

I have a ListView with DataPager control. I'm trying to display a series of questions.Each question along with it's choices belongs to an item in the listview and I am displaying one question per page. The choices are radio buttons with autopostback enabled.
Now, based on the user's response to the first question I want to filter the rest of the questions in the listview to display only the ones relevant to the user's choice. Also, I don't want to completely remove the other questions from the listview  because if the user navigates to the first question and changes his response, I want the list to change accordingly. Is there a way to dynamically hide the pages that contain the irrelevant questions?

Thanks.

Note: The list items are populated by a custom sql query:
`SELECT questionNumber,questionText,OptionA,OptionB,OptionC,OptionD,OptionE,OptionF,OptionG,OptionH,OptionI,OptionJ,OptionK,OptionL,Other,questionTag,subType from Questionairre`

In this query the value present in the field "subType" should be compared with the choice made in the first question.. The subtype field for the first question will not be checked.  The following code is what I have so far. The variable "firstChoice" is the static variable that stores the value postedback from the first question.

```
 protected void ListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        ListViewDataItem di = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;

        Label q=new Label();
        foreach(Control control in di.Controls)
        {

            if (control.GetType() == typeof(Label))
            {
                q = (Label)control;

                if (q.ID == "subType" && q.Text != firstChoice)
                    {
                        di.Visible = false;


                    }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: what code samples of your own do you have thus far..?

Comment: Well, I am not sure which part of the code to post. I'll tell you what I've done so far:
1) The method that handles postback for the choices records the choice made for the first question in a static variable.
2) In the listview ItemDataBound , I grab a label control from each question and compare the text with that of the static variable. If it's not the same, then I simply hide the data item. 
But the problem is, this doesn't hide the page in the datapager. So I find myself navigating through blank pages.

Comment: Show the code that deals with the user selecting the ListView Item and or how you are loading / populating the list items

Comment: Post your code in the same portion where you posted your initial question .. not here in the comments section thanks